# SharedPreferences fail to save data if setting APP_OPTIM := release

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, sharedpreferences

the SharedPreferences is called through jni from c++ code.
When `APP_OPTIM := debug`,  the preference is saved, but not for release.

What does `APP_OPTIM := release` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: 
  It turns out the in the jni code, the return is omitted, perhaps with APP_OPTIM := debug, 
  the return is added and for release, the return is omitted.

```
int getPreference(string x)
{
    jniGetPreference(x);
}


int getPreference(string x)
{
    return jniGetPreference(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to learn what `APP_OPTIM=release` does. Simply run

```
ndk-build -B V=1 APP_OPTIM=debug
```

and

```
ndk-build -B V=1 APP_OPTIM=release
```

and compare the build logs.

Regarding your first question, it is most likely that the C++ optimization does not clean up some memory, and the `SharedPreferences.Editor.commit()` is not called, or called on a different instance of `SharedPreferences.Editor` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9677788/192373 for example).